# How to rescale a given interpolationfunction, thereby keeping the original name?

Tags: function-construction

For a given Blackbox interpolation function `f[x]` examplary

```
f = Interpolation[Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20}]] (*f[x]*)
```

I would like to rescale the function

```
eps=0.9;
fn=eps f[#/eps]&; (*fn[x]:= eps f[x/eps]*)
```

which makes no problem if I use a new function name `fn`.

My question: Is it possible to easily overwrite the original functiondefinition  `f[x]` in this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean something like `f = Evaluate[eps f[#/eps]] &;`?  You can only do it once, or you get a repeated composition.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes that's it. Thanks!  I tried it without `Evaluate` and got recursion error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple way that works with any function `f`, but should be done once only; otherwise, the rescalings will be compounded with each iteration:

```
f = Evaluate[eps f[#/eps]] &
```

Another way that may be executed repeatedly and does not have the compounding problem, but it assumes `f` is originally an `InterpolatingFunction`:

```
f /. if_InterpolatingFunction :> 
   RuleCondition[f = eps if[#/eps] &; if];
f
```

*Update:* Here is another way for the second alternative. The difference is that the replacement fails but still has the same side effect. `TracePrint` reveals no significant difference between them in this case, probably because the `InterpolatingFunction` is inert and/or `Function` (`&`) is `HoldAll`.

```
f /. if_InterpolatingFunction :>
   if /; TrueQ[f = eps if[#/eps] &];
```

Comment: do you think [Once](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Once.html) would work in this connection?

Comment: @kglr It might depend. If you change `f` (new interpolation) after `Once[..]` and need to rescale it, then I think `Once` won't rescale it for you.  You could execute something like `If[ValueQ[Once[..]], Unset[Once[..]]]` first.  But sometimes it should be appropriate.

Comment: meant something like `f = Interpolation[Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20}]];Once[f = Evaluate[eps f[#/eps]] &]`

Comment: @kglr No, wait, I think it doesn't work `f = Interpolation[Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20}]]; Once[
 f = Evaluate[eps f[#/eps]] &];
f = Interpolation[Table[{x, Sin[x]^3}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20}]]; Once[
 f = Evaluate[eps f[#/eps]] &]; f`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your second variant also creates an `InterpolationFunction`, but is only once executable! Why? Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The `if` matches the original `InterpolatingFunction` (which is the original `f` here), and `f = eps if[#/eps] &; if];` sets `f` equal to the scaled `if` as a side effect of the replacement.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Very tricky, thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Shouldn't the single `=`  in your update version `f /. if_InterpolatingFunction :>
   if /; TrueQ[f = eps if[#/eps] &];` be a double `==`? Both variants seem to work! Thanks.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Is this what you mean?: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yki6G.png -- It doesn't seem to work for me with `==` where I put it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, and on Mathematica v12(Windoes10) both variants work (I just tried it with fresh kernel)!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann How interesting! I know no reason why the `==` variant would change `f`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Neither do I. Because `TrueQ` argument is boolean I tried it

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way that can be used in further tweaking:

```
f = Interpolation[Table[{x, Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/20}]]

Block[{eps = 0.9},
 f = Interpolation @
   Transpose[{
     First@Rescale[f["Coordinates"], First@f["Domain"], {0, eps}], 
     eps*f["ValuesOnGrid"]}
   ]
 ]
```

````
f // InputForm

(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.9}}, {5, 7, 0, {21}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, 
  False}, {{0., 0.045, 0.09, 0.135, 0.18, 0.225, 0.27, 0.315, 0.36, 0.405, 0.45, 
  0.49500000000000005, 0.54, 0.585, 0.63, 0.675, 0.72, 0.765, 0.81, 0.855, 0.9}}, 
 {Developer`PackedArrayForm, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
  17, 18, 19, 20, 21}, {0.9, 0.8559508646656382, 0.7281152949374528, 0.5290067270632258, 
  0.27811529493745274, 0., -0.27811529493745274, -0.5290067270632258, 
  -0.7281152949374528, -0.8559508646656382, -0.9, -0.8559508646656382, 
  -0.7281152949374528, -0.5290067270632258, -0.27811529493745274, 0., 
  0.27811529493745274, 0.5290067270632258, 0.7281152949374528, 0.8559508646656382, 
  0.9}}, {Automatic}] *)
```
````

Comment: Thanks, my version `Interpolation[
 Transpose[{f["Coordinates"][[1]]/eps , f["ValuesOnGrid"] eps}]]` also works